# Unregister Events MultiCastDelegate Performance Problem

Tags: c#, performance, events, event-handling

I have a problem: Our application has grown so far and therefore there is an object with many many EventHandlers. The point here is that removing them takes far more time, than adding them. This can be tested very fast:

1. Create a class with a
   public event EventHandler
2. Make a second time and register to the event in first class like 300'000 times.

Here comes the interesting point: Registring needs like 0.1 seconds, whereas deregistring needs 5 minutes and it's growing almost exponentially.

Does anyone have a solution for that? The only one I found is to solve it over a WeakEventHandler (with it's downsides), but maybe there is another possiblity.

Example:

```
  
public class ClassWithValueChangedEvent
  {
    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;
    
    public ClassWithValueChangedEvent()
    {
      
    }
  }

 public class MainWindowViewModel
  {
   
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
      DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
      var classInstance = new ClassWithValueChangedEvent();
      for (int i = 0; i < 300000; i++)
      {
        classInstance.ValueChanged += ClassWithValueChangedOnValueChanged;
      }
      Debug.WriteLine($"Elapsed Time: {(DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds}");

      start = DateTime.Now;
      for (int i = 0; i < 300000; i++)
      {
        classInstance.ValueChanged -= ClassWithValueChangedOnValueChanged;
      }
      Debug.WriteLine($"Elapsed Time: {(DateTime.Now - start).TotalSeconds}");
```

Comment: It would be nice if you can supply a quick example so that we can work on.

Comment: use `HashSet<EventHandler> EventHanders` instead multicast ... [Multicast seems to be based on array](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/multicastdelegate.cs,c2a5d5528659658f)  so searching for given event to delate takes O(N)  ... (but then you have to call it like `foreach(var e in EventHanders) { e.Invoke(); }` instead simple `ValueChanged.Invoke()`) and adding will looks like `EventsHandle.Add(...)` not `ValueChange += ...`

Comment: Do you need to remove all event handlers?

Comment: @Selvin, yes that what really strikes me, that microsoft iterates through the whole array. That's why it takes so long :)... and it's the usual way when you do += . I'll look if that is easy to change in our application, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question in using the WeakEventManager<>.AddHandler() from microsoft, which does not immediately remove the event handlers. It did not matter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

**If we need to remove all event handlers**

What I would do is that I would create an `Unset` method inside the class that nullifies the `ValueChanged` event handler like bellow:

```
public class ClassWithValueChangedEvent
{
    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

    public void Unset()
    {
        ValueChanged = null;
    }
}
```

Then, when needed I would do:

```
classInstance.Unset();
```

This is almost instantaneous.

**If we need to remove individual event handlers**

The process bellow is much more complicated and I don't know if I would choose it if I was in such need. The idea is that we create a custom list and we invoke the handlers manually:

```
public class ClassWithValueChangedEvent
{
    private List<EventHandler> eventHandlers = new List<EventHandler>();

    public void SetEventHandler(EventHandler evt)
    {
        eventHandlers.Add(evt);
    }

    public void UnsetEventHandler(EventHandler evt)
    {
        eventHandlers.Remove(evt);
    }

    public void UnsetAll()
    {
        eventHandlers.Clear();
    }

    public void CallEventHandlers(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        eventHandlers.All(p => { p(sender, e); return true; });
    }
}
```

Then, the methods of this class can be called as:

```
classInstance.SetEventHandler(ClassWithValueChangedOnValueChanged);
classInstance.CallEventHandlers(null, null);
classInstance.UnsetEventHandler(ClassWithValueChangedOnValueChanged);
```

Removing 300000 event handlers takes around 9 seconds which is much faster than minutes. I guess also that there must be a much faster way to do something like that.

Comment: Thanks for answering, that works. But in the "real" application I don't need to release really all events, but almost. Then it does not work.